# source files ordering in minification

Tags: javascript, css, minify, bundling-and-minification

Looking a bit to minification topics, the [usage guide](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/usage.html) of the *Minify* plugin mentions the rules used for the merge order.

What I am wondering is why this information should matter at al.

If we consider CSS source files, the ordering in which they are minified and combined should not matter, because what "simply" happens is that more specific rules override more general ones; the browser never sees CSS in terms of individual stylesheets and if there are multiple stylesheets, they are all treated as if they were one giant stylesheet and rules are evaluated accordingly.

What can we say about the merge order of a set of JS files? Does the order in which they are minified and combined matter?

Comment: Javascript statements are executed in order. If you have dependencies, you need to order them correctly -- you can't call a function before it has been defined.

Comment: CSS order can matter: https://www.quora.com/How-does-CSS-file-order-matter

Comment: perfect, sometimes obvious things escape